# arduino nano fried (TWICE!!)

Tags: arduino-nano, hardware

Having the skill to be stupid has managed to fry not one but 2 Arduino nano boards in the same place (I think it is because this part that smoke came out from of has a lump on it that was not there before). I have heard that Arduino boards are open source, but I have not found anything explaining which part I have fried. Therefore, I don't know the function, so I cannot replace it. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could point out the part name or a link to a shop with it in stock so I could purchase it or give me a copy of the PCB schematics to make my own Arduino.
I think the part is called the "usb diode"[image: arduino nano]
Thanks

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: is there a way to fix it without getting a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the several Arduino Nano schematics I've found, the "fried" part you identify as the USB diode, might be a MBR0520 Schottky diode or a similar diode with a low forward voltage drop. These parts are polarized and should be replaced in the same orientation as the original part.

There is no guarantee that this is the only damaged component on your Nano.

Comment: would the anwser change if i mentioned that this is an arduino clone

Comment: The clones that I've found schematics for, have similar Schottky diodes. Still, no guarantees.

Comment: somehow, one still works! I don't know how, and don't want to question it!